# Who is the narrator speaking about here?

Tags: meaning

The bold line in the below appears ambiguous to me. His friend asked if they can stop by the crepe cart on the way home and they both bought one. Based on what has been said here and a bit before we know that they are childhood friends and often buy crepes from here. However, I am unclear whether his statement is about himself, or his friend. I'm guessing their is some word choice/context that makes it obvious that I am missing.

> Protagonist「またかよ？　本当にあそこのクレープ好きだな」
>
> Girl「へっへー。そりゃね？　あたしを育ててくれた味なんだから」
>
> Protagonist「うん、うまい。ここのクレープはクリームをケチってないのがいいよな」
>
> Girl「同感、同感。至福だよこれは」
>
> **はちきれんばかりのクレープを夢中で貪るうちに、口の周りがべたべたになるのもガキの頃から変わらない。**
>
> いつもの駅前広場の、いつもの時間。中央にある噴水を眺めたり、ハトに餌をやったり。
>
> 様々な人たちが、この場所では思い思いにくつろいだ時間を過ごしていた。

Comment: Ambiguous per this piece of context. Himself, her, or both.

Comment: What's this from? If the speaker has been reminiscing about *his* past in previous passages, he may just as well be talking about his own experiences in this one as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ambiguous, but I think this sentence is probably about **anyone** who is eating this crepe. Reasons:

- This sentence lacks a specific proper noun or personal pronoun, which may indicate the subject of 食べる is unimportant.
- The previous two sentences are also about the volume of the cream.